# KendoUI Grid Save when Pressing Enter

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I click on a cell to edit it, and then press enter, nothing happens.

How can I make the grid save when the enter key is pressed?

I have tried binding the keycode in the edit handler and that doesn't work.

I need it to save the contents of the cell for good usability in my app. At the moment the only way to save grid contents is by clicking off the cell.

Answer (score 5):

You can try enabling the [navigatable](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-navigatable) configuration option of the grid.

Comment: Had already tried that, but it doesn't save on enter and just returns the selection to the first cell in my grid :(

Comment: Could you provide sample project and more information about the exact browser, KendoUI and jQuery version used to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

With inspiration from here: https://www.telerik.com/forums/save-in-cell-edits-before-calling-editcell-or-calling-close-cell I did this:

```
var $grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    ...
    cellClose: function(e) {
        if (e.model.dirty) {
            // call save method
        }
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");

// catch enter keydown and call closeCell
$grid.table.on("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $grid.closeCell();
        });
    }
});
```